ArrayInput with AutocompleteArrayInput not showing default values
I'm trying to create a form using React-Admin where I have an ArrayInput containing an AutocompleteArrayInput. I want to pre-select certain values, but the defaultValue is not being displayed.
Here's my simplified code:
  Edit, 
  SimpleForm, 
  ArrayInput, 
  SimpleFormIterator, 
  AutocompleteArrayInput 
} from "react-admin";

const EditComponent = () => {
  // Sample data that would normally come from an API
  const questions = [
    { id: 1, title: "Question 1" },
    { id: 2, title: "Question 2" },
  ];

  const defaultSection = {
    order: 1,
    questions: [1], // We want this question to be pre-selected
  };

  return (
    <Edit>
      <SimpleForm>
        <ArrayInput source="sections" defaultValue={[defaultSection]}>
          <SimpleFormIterator>
            <AutocompleteArrayInput
              source="questions"
              choices={questions}
              optionText="title"
              optionValue="id"
              parse={v => v}
              format={v => v}
            />
          </SimpleFormIterator>
        </ArrayInput>
      </SimpleForm>
    </Edit>
  );
};

export default EditComponent;

I expect the AutocompleteArrayInput to show "Question 1" as pre-selected since I'm passing [1] in the defaultSection, but nothing appears selected. I've tried using both defaultValue and parse/format props but still no success.
What am I missing to make the default values appear in the AutocompleteArrayInput?

Just tried in a Stackblitz (go to Post Create) and it seems to work like a charm. Do you reproduce your issue in this sandbox?
